# Axios taking time to send api response in React application

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, axios

I am making get request with axios in my react.js application, but axios is taking more time to send a response.
I have also tested the API with the postman, which is taking less time relative to axios.
I don't understand why axios is talking much time to process and send a response.

**Axios instance is as follows:**

```
  getAxiosInstance(headers = {}) {
        return axios.create({
            baseURL: Env.getConnections().api,
            timeout: 100000,
            headers: headers
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you eventually get a result, or is it not working? Check the Console and Network tabs of your Developer Tools to see if something went wrong.

Comment: Yes I get the results, but it takes more time with respect to the postman

Answer (score 1):

use axios.defaults.timeout = 100000; instead

```
 getAxiosInstance(headers = {}) {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: Env.getConnections().api,
        axios.defaults.timeout: 100000,
        headers: headers
    });
}
```